# Why are my array values changing?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I'm trying to initialize an int array, but when I go back to reference it, my values change as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDWkq.png). For example my values {010, 011} are changing to {8,9}. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not without your code they can't, and I for one am not going "off site" to look at your code.

Comment: Are you trying to store binary values? loose the leading 0's

Answer (score 3):

Numbers starting with a zero are treated as octal by the compiler.

010 in octal is 8.

Maybe just use `10` to initialise the values.

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By prefixing the 10 with 0, you are telling the compiler that it is an octal number(base-8 number). To solve this, simply initialize your values as {10,11}